# Why are the results of RNG same every time?

Tags: c++, opencv, random

I have a problem about RNG class. I want to get different point randomly from a given image, so I use the [RNG class](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=rng#rng) which is recommended in the OpenCV documentation. The code is:

```
struct SingleAnt
{
    int row;
    int col;
};
void initializeAnts( SingleAnt *ants, Mat *sourceImage )
{
    RNG rng( 0xFFFFFFFF );
    int imgWidth = sourceImage->cols;
    int imgHight = sourceImage->rows;

    for( int index = 0; index < ANTSNUMBER; index++ ) {
        ants[ index ].col = rng.uniform( 0, imgWidth );
        ants[ index ].row = rng.uniform( 0, imgHight );
    }
}
```

However, when I run this code, I get the same result every time. Are there any mistakes in the code?

Comment: yes, as you're seeding the rng with the same value `0xFFFFFFFF` all generated values will be the same, you should seed your rng only 1 time during application start and then use the same instance of it

Answer (score 5):

```
RNG rng( 0xFFFFFFFF );
```

Here you are (presumably) providing the [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) with a [seed value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) - specifically *the same* seed value (`0xFFFFFFFF`) every time the code runs.  Because of this, the PRNG (being a completely deterministic algorithm) is going to provide the same sequence of output values every time.

Instead, you should provide it with a pseudo-random seed value. Typically, the system `time()` value is used to seed a PRNG.  Many times, calling a parameter-less constructor for a PRNG actually does this for you.

As [B...](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2151446/b) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920568/why-are-the-results-of-rng-same-every-time/19920580?noredirect=1#comment29642959_19920580), The `cv::RNG` class does have a parameterless constructor: [`cv::RNG::RNG()`](http://physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/manuals/opencv/classcv_1_1RNG.html#a06c28035e383bc9eff22e1fad619ddf6), but it *does not* seed the generator.  From the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=rng#rng), `RNG::RNG()` only

> sets the state to some pre-defined value, equal to 2**32-1 in the current implementation

So as I previously suggested, you should seed it yourself.

Comment: From http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=rng#rng, RNG::RNG() "sets the state to some pre-defined value, equal to 2**32-1 in the current implementation". And here is its code `inline RNG::RNG() { state = 0xffffffff; }`.  So if you want to seed from the time, you will have to do it yourself

Comment: @B... Thanks a lot, I spent a few minutes digging and didn't find that information. I edited my answer to include some of that information.